# How to query mongo collection based on the dbref fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm using spring boot with mongodb. I have three collections which relations internally. Please find the collections and relations below.

```
@Document(collection="brands")
public class Brand{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

@Document(collection="models")
public class Model{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @DBRef
    private Brand brand;
    @DBRef
    private Country country;
}

@Document(collection="country")
public class Country{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

I want to know the **Brands where models.name is equal to 'SUV' and model.country.name is equal to 'Some Country Name'**.

Please help me to find the right path.

Comment: You can write an aggregation pipeline following this article https://stackabuse.com/spring-data-mongodb-guide-to-the-aggregation-annotation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Aggregations with Spring boot.

Here is the reference >> https://stackabuse.com/spring-data-mongodb-guide-to-the-aggregation-annotation/